# Need help to create deep copy of map which has value as complex object type

Tags: java, gson

We were using gson to create a copy of map and do some updates in copy
map which would not reflect in original map. But gson is holding
thread it seems we find lot of its entries in heapdump and memory keeps increasing. due to this, we see requests getting rejected. So we were
being asked alternative for deep copy of map.

Because we see deep copy is not happening in value object of map if we
do orgMap.clone()/copy constructor(new
HashMap<>(orgMap)/copymap.putall(orgMap). In this way, if we do changes in value object in copy map , it reflects in both original map and copy map.

```
> Processing Thread 13running , holding [ at
> com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:593) at
> com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:433) at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:244)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:241)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.readIntoField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$FieldReflectionAdapter.readField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:433)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:393)
> at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.read(Gson.java:1367) at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.readIntoField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$FieldReflectionAdapter.readField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:433)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:393)
> at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.read(Gson.java:1367) at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.readIntoField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$FieldReflectionAdapter.readField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:433)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:393)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:144)
> at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1227) at
> com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1137) at
> com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1047) at
> com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1014) at
> com.util.getDeepCopyOfMap(Utils.java:2398) at
> com.util.ParameterPopulation.applyFiltering(ParameterPopulation.java:800)
> at
> com.util.ParameterPopulation.populateSchemaParameters(ParameterPopulation.java:506)
> at
> com.util.ParameterPopulation.formAvroRequestBasedOnSession(ParameterPopulation.java:440)
> at
> com.util.ParameterPopulation.populateLocationRelatedParameters(ParameterPopulation.java:1343)
> at
> com.util.ParameterPopulation.localProcess(ParameterPopulation.java:294)
> at
> com.util.AbstractProcessingActivity.process(AbstractProcessingActivity.java:30)
> at com.util.TransactionImpl.run(TransactionImpl.java:415) at
> com.util.TransactionHandlerImpl$FaultTolerantTransaction.run(TransactionHandlerImpl.java:466)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.20/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.20/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.20/Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it manually? Iterate entries and in new map put key -> value.clone() (or however you have implemented cloning the complex value type).

Comment: our value object structure is complex, it would be like Enrichment->childNode where child node itself an Enrichment type and it goes on n-depth if an enrichment has child enrichment node. So cloning value enrichment object does not clone child node right?